# Deep copy of OrderedDict child

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I have experimented with `deepcopy` from `copy` module. It works well with OrderedDict instance and with instance of dict child. But it doesn't work with instance of OrderedDict child. Here is a demo:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from copy import deepcopy

class Example2(dict):
    def __init__(self,l):
        dict.__init__(self,l)

class Example3(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self,l):
        OrderedDict.__init__(self,l)

d1=OrderedDict([(1,1),(2,2)]) 
print(deepcopy(d1))           #OrderedDict([(1, 1), (2, 2)])

d2=Example2([(1,1),(2,2)])
print(deepcopy(d2))           #{1: 1, 2: 2}

d3=Example3([(1,1),(2,2)])
print(deepcopy(d3))
```

First two examples work as expected but the last one crashes with an exception:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'l'
```

So the question is: what is actually the problem here and is it possible to use the `deepcopy` function for this situation at all?

Comment: You need to itterate through it and deepcopy every element on its own

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the constructor in your Example3 class, deepcopy will call the default constructor (the no argument one) but you have not defined this, thus the crash. If you change your constructor definition to use optional arguments for the list instead, it will work

Like so

```
class Example3(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, l = []):
        OrderedDict.__init__(self, l)
```

then

```
>>> d3 = Example3([(1, 1), (2, 2)])
>>> print(deepcopy(d3))
Example3([(1, 1), (2, 2)])
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Although, I should admit that I don't fully understand why Example2 works while Example3 doesn't.

Comment: Good point! Cant find proof of it but suspect it is due to dict beeing an build in type so deepcopy can handle it different

Comment: Just to mention that I have got the same error in a similar case, although I used dict.copy() instead of deepcopy's.